# Rounding Error Problem

Tags: magento-1.7, tax, rounding

In Magento 1.7 there is a well known **rounding error** issue, which I thought I have solved using the fix suggested for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529580/magento-tax-rounding-issue)

However, ever since I have applied the fix, there is now a very strange **new calculation error**, not for taxes, but already for the items in cart. It only happens when the amount of an item in the cart is more than one.

**Example**:  5 times an item with a price of 1.18 € each equals 5.88 € in cart and not 5.90 € as supposed.

Once I disable the rounding error fix again, price calculation for the articles works again, bit than tax is being calculated wrong.

Any idea how to fox this?

Comment: take a look on this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15846/why-does-magento-store-a-rounding-delta-when-calculating-taxes/25436#25436

Comment: Have you tried the extension [Itabs_BetterPriceRounding](https://github.com/therouv/Magento-BetterPriceRounding)? Solves all rounding issues for me.

Comment: Same result as when applying the core fix. Tax is being calculated correctly, but items aren't.

Answer (score 1):

## Info

Round price in Magento based on previous rounding operation delta.

> [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php:1392](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.3.7/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php#L1392)
> [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php:719](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.3.7/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php#L719)

```
protected function _deltaRound($price, $rate, $direction, $type = 'regular')
{
    if ($price) {
        $rate = (string)$rate;
        $type = $type . $direction;
        // initialize the delta to a small number to avoid non-deterministic behavior with rounding of 0.5
        $delta = isset($this->_roundingDeltas[$type][$rate]) ? $this->_roundingDeltas[$type][$rate] : 0.000001;
        $price += $delta;
        $this->_roundingDeltas[$type][$rate] = $price - $this->_calculator->round($price);
        $price = $this->_calculator->round($price);
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Sometimes this can cause an error due to the high delta calculation error (`$this->_calculator->round($price)`). For example, for this reason, some prices can vary in the range of **±1 cent**.

## Solution

To avoid this, you need to improve the accuracy of the delta calculation.

Change

```
$this->_roundingDeltas[$type][$rate] = $price - $this->_calculator->round($price);
```

to

```
$this->_roundingDeltas[$type][$rate] = $price - round($price, 4);
```

Changes need to be made in both files:

> [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php:1392](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.3.7/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php#L1392)
> [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php:719](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.3.7/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php#L719)

**Don't modify or hack core files! Do a rewrite!**

The solution was tested on different versions of Magento 1.9.x, but maybe this will work in earlier versions.

## P.S.

Change `roundPrice` function, as shown below, can solve the rounding error problem, but it can cause others (for example, some platforms require rounding up to 2 decimal places).

> [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:995](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/bea006a3fe4c87dc87a262e379ba879c7c4f8805/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php#L995)

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 4);
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me, Kindly try with a product $95.00 and Shipping $0.00, the product amount is Incl. of tax Tax rate is 7%. I calculated tax on Incl. price and based on "Row Total"

Comment: @Yogita, what are the prices before and after the changes? Both methods of solving the problem were tested? What version of Magento? Are there any extensions for rounding?

Comment: I have done this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225168/magento1-9-paypal-rounding-amount-issue and Using Magento1.9.2.4, My product is Incl. of tax and having 7% tax rate, Product price $95.00

Comment: @Yogita, I answered [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/226520/51527).