# Magento 2: Discount in row total, incorrect rounding by 1 cent

Tags: magento-2.1

Where can I configure how Magento does round?
I have the issue that it seems to alternate the rounding method.

I got an order with 3 lines, each having subtotal of 22.50, Discount is 25%. Now it does for the first line calculate a discount of 16.87, second 16.88, third 16.87.
Correct would be 16.88 or 16.875.

I have magento-2.1.9 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it makes sure that rounding errors do not add up.

The System is called Delta Rounding, and there is an answer about this already here: [Why does Magento store a rounding delta when calculating taxes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/15846)